# Optimizing an IP generation method

Tags: optimization, delphi, networking

I have designed a proxy server which has the feature to manage miniature separate networks. Each network has space to have up to 500 nodes or 500 IPs. The code for getting a new virtual IP is based on a bit flag based approach. I have used an array of DWORD (Blocks) so as to skip entire 32 IP chunks, if the block is fully set. I have also divided the DWORD further into byte based checking. so as to forgo checking of all 32 bits as much as possible. The code also skips any addresses with the lower octet being 0 or 1. The code only gets the lower two octets while the higher two octets are fixed to 10.0.

I know the problem with this approach is that the higher the IP, the slower it gets found. So how can I diminish the slow down? Should I go higher towards LongWORD for one block? Should I check the Block byte by byte or in smaller/bigger chunks? Or just abandon this and find some other algorithm?

The limit to be 500 is more of a marketing move than a technical one. We currently have to manage 1800 such networks. These networks are academic in nature and have very anomalous behavior patterns, as such that we are seeing almost 10000 requests per second in peak times.

```
---

var
  fIPPool : array [0..15] of DWORD;

---

constructor xxxx;
begin

  fIPPool [0]  := $00000003; // Skips 0.0 and 0.1
  fIPPool [7]  := $80000000; // Skips 0.255
  fIPPool [8]  := $00000003; // Skips 1.0 and 1.1
  fIPPool [15] := $FE000000; // Skips 1.249-1.255

end;

---

function GetIP: DWORD;
var
  Block, Cell : Byte;
  Mask : DWORD

  function GetCell ( const ABlock: DWORD; var AMask: DWORD; const ACell : Byte )
                   : Byte; inline;
  begin
    Result := ACell;
    while ( ABlock and AMask ) <> 0 do
    begin
      Result := Result + 1;
      AMask := AMask shl 1;
    end;
  end;

begin

  Result := 0;
  for Block := 0 to 15 do
  begin

    if fIPPool [Block] <> $FFFFFFFF then
    begin

      if ( fIPPool [Block] and $000000FF ) < $000000FF then
      begin
        Mask := $00000001;
        Cell := GetCell ( fIPPool [Block], Mask, 0 )
      end
      else if ( fIPPool [Block] and $0000FFFF ) < $0000FFFF then
      begin
        Mask := $00000100;
        Cell := GetCell ( fIPPool [Block], Mask, 8 )
      end
      else if ( fIPPool [Block] and $00FFFFFF ) < $00FFFFFF then
      begin
        Mask := $00010000;
        Cell := GetCell ( fIPPool [Block], Mask, 16 );
      end
      else
      begin
        Mask := $01000000;
        Cell := GetCell ( fIPPool [Block], Mask, 24 );
      end;

      Result := ( Block * 32 ) + Cell;
      fIPPool [Block] := fIPPool [Block] or Mask;
      break;

    end;

  end;

end;

// one can use the following line to get the IPs if run in a for-loop for 500 times
Memo1.Lines.Add
( IntToStr ( ( IP and $FF00 ) shr 8 ) +'.'+ IntToStr ( IP and $00FF ));
```

Comment: Can you add some detail about why you have 500 and not 512 addresses in each block?

Comment: Also, how many of these networks do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have performed some benchmarks to get the optimum combination of block and slice sizes using 32-bit and 64-bit compiler. 64-bit because we are also developing an optimized 64-bit implementation on the sidelines. Here are the results for generating 320000 IPs on our server with all the server applications also running, the values are in Milli-seconds and floored over 5 runs;

```
Block-Slice  32-bit 64-bit
32-0         3479   3120
32-16        3464   5912
64-0         2059   2980
64-16        2028   1606
64-32        2013   1622
```

The algorithm gave the worst results with 8-bit slices.
So the best bets are 64-32 for 32-bit and 64-16 for 64-bit for this algorithm.